# Why does my extruding not work like this?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, extrude

[image]

This is what mine looks like. Here is what I would like it to look like:
[image]
I cannot figure out why the edges of mine are not expanding like in the tutorial I'm following. I'd appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: is there a difference? on the video he just pulled it a bit less, no?

Comment: If you look at the edges of the area that I'm extruding close up it seems that his is different. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: If you zoom in you can see that the edges of his connect different to mine. I'm having trouble uploading the file. Is it not possible for you to see it through the images?

Comment: or use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/fb1db737779542e6810c86a0fae60695

Comment: Also try disabling the snap function. It also create problems sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You have overlapping vertices, it messes up your extrusion, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

The threshold in the *Operator* box should be enough.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it to work. I am new to Blender, could you possibly explain what you mean by the threshold in the operator box?

Comment: I've edited my answer, the Operator box is on the bottom left of your 3D view, it appears as soon as you make an action that can be set up, here you can set the merge distance, it means that the merge operation won't happen between vertices that are separated by more than the distance.

Comment: @Morgan You had probably extruded the face and where moving the extruded vertices and then cancelled it. Cancelling the extrusion snaps the new vertices back on top of the original vertices.